# Como fazer insert com valores postados em textarea

Tags: php, mysqli

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uso de textarea juntamente com php e mysqli para fazer o seguinte preciso enviar 12 itens dentro de uma textarea e que estes  itens sejam postos com quebra de linha e que aplique insert desses 12 itens na mysqli sendo que caso não poste todos os 12 não de erro só necessito que no max só permita 12 itens por textarea, caso poste menor o igual a 12 funcione perfeitamente.

Pois eu tenho na tabela media 12 campos para por os links.

No caso necessito que envie da forma que esta a **textarea** e **SQL** abaixo de forma que cada posição no caso e uma coluna na tabela media que vai da coluna link1 ate link12.

```
<textarea rows="12" name="links">
link1
link2
link3
link4
link5
link6
link7
link8
link9
link10
link11
link12
</textarea>
```

Mysql

```
CREATE DATABASE `media` ;
CREATE TABLE `media`.`medias` (
`id` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`link1` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link2` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link3` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link4` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link5` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link6` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link7` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link8` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link9` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link10` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link11` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`link12` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Comment: o que voce ja conseguiu fazer ? tem algum exemplo a acrescentar na pergunta ?

Comment: Infelismente não só tenho a text área e os dados Mysql.

Comment: Tem como mostrar como os dados são enviados no textarea?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: O ideal era um unica coluna de link mais o `id` de algum outra tabela. Se não for possível mudar isso da para resolver com `$link = explode("\n",$_POST['textarea']);`

Comment: no caso para eu por na posição que eu quero terei que fazer algo assim $link1 = $link[0]; ate $link12 = $link[11]; certo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que você está fazendo isso não é uma das melhores, nem a forma mais correta de se fazer, o ideal seria criar campos de input="text", e com um botão ir replicando e outro para remover, com limite de até os 12 inputs todos como o mesmo name name="urls[]", e lá no php recolher o $_POST['urls'] dentro de um foreach e gravar a lista de url, validando cada uma. Todavia, para fazer como você quer, a forma de fazer isso é basicamente validando tanto no javascript como no php. No javascript, você limita o campo para o número máximo de quebras, que no caso são 11, já que a última não precisa quebrar. E no php, você coloca todos os itens num array, e faz um foreach dos valores:

Então ficaria algo assim:

***Javascript para filtrar:***

```
function checkUrl(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\/\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\#[-a-z\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locater
  if(!pattern.test(str)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function getListURL(valor, total) {
var listValid = 0;
var urlValida = [];
   var urls = valor.split("\n");
   for (var i = 0; i < total - 1; i++) {
      if (checkUrl(urls[i])) {
           urlValida[listValid] = urls[i];
           listValid++;
      }
   }
  return urlValida;
}

function setFilter() {
var arrUrls = getListURL(document.urls, 12);
    document.sendURLs.urls = arrUrls.join("\n");
    document.sendURLs.submit();
}
```

***PHP para capturar e atualizar o registro:***

```
$urls = explode("\n", $_POST['urls']);
$id = $_POST['id'];

$cps = array();
$pos = 1;

foreach ($urls as $url) {
  if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false && $pos <= 12) {
         $cps[]  = "link" . $pos ." = '{$url}'";
        $pos++;
  }
}

$campos = implode(", ",$cps);
 $sql = "UPDATE media SET $campos WHERE id = '$id';";
```