# Inserir valor do botão em base de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

No meu projeto estou a criar botões (em troca de um formulário) com o nome das tarefas para registar diariamente, assim torna-se mais prático e mais rápido o registo.

**Código com os botões:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="PequenoAlmoco" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="PequenoAlmoco" name="PequenoAlmoco" class="btn btn-info">Pequeno Almoço</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Almoco" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="Almoco" name="Almoco" class="btn btn-info">Almoço</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Lanche" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="Lanche" name="Lanche" class="btn btn-info">Lanche</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Jantar" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="Jantar" name="Jantar" class="btn btn-info">Jantar</button>
</div>
</div>
```

O meu problema é como guardo as tarefas que o utilizador clica em variáveis e faço o `insert` na tabela da base de dados.

Comment: sua pergunta me parece ampla demais, acho que precisa mais de um tutorial do que uma ajuda mais específica. Já olhou as outras perguntas sobre inserir dado com php aqui mesmo no site? Tipo essas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76766/como-fazer-insert-com-valores-postados-em-textarea e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248757/como-inserir-valor-no-mysql-com-php-e-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isto eh necessário utilizar Ajax e php vamos la vou criar um exemplo bem simples para voce entender melhor:

```
<button type="button" id="pequeno-almoco">Pequeno Almoço</button> <!-- Botão para executar a ação -->

<div id="resposta"></div> <!-- Aqui sera exibida a resposta da ação fica a critério  -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

         $(document).on("click","#pequeno-almoco",function(e) { //Apos clicar no botão ativa o evento onclick

            var p_almoco = $(this).attr('id'); //Variavel de onde recebe o valor do id do botão 

            //Ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: 'almoco.php', //Url para onde sera passado o parametro via POST
                type: 'POST',      
                data: {p_almoco : p_almoco}, //Passando o valor da variavel para o post     
                cache: false,
                success: function(returnhtml) {                          
                    $("#resposta").html(returnhtml); //Resposta da ação 
                }           
            });    
            //
        });

    });
    //
    </script>
```

No seu php almoco.php

```
$valor = $_POST['p_almoco'];
```

Com essa variável recebida pelo post faça o update no banco de dados, faça a mesma coisa para os outros botoes.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que entendi, você pode colocar em um <`form`> e esses botões serem um *input* do tipo *submit*. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<form method="POST"> 
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="PequenoAlmoco" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" id="PequenoAlmoco" name="tarefa" value="PequenoAlmoco" class="btn btn-info">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="PequenoAlmoco" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" id="Almoco" name="tarefa" value="Almoco" class="btn btn-info">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Depois é só pegar o valor no $_POST['tarefa']. Acredito que assim fica mais fácil